# Change pytest's live log level during runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'm using pytest's [Live Logs feature](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs) to see the logging records as they're generated. I'm currently setting the log level in the `pytest.ini` file, as per the docs, using the `log_cli_level` entry. However, it would be fairly practical to be able to change the log level from the code.

After some inspection of the pytest code, I can see it sets the [`self.log_cli_level` field](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/e398c93884f228c9808adf9d0be2f876719e703d/src/_pytest/logging.py#L564) in the `LoggingPlugin` class. This plugin is [registered with the pluginmanager here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/e398c93884f228c9808adf9d0be2f876719e703d/src/_pytest/logging.py#L518), with the key `"logging-plugin"`.

I guess it would be a matter of accessing the plugin using the [`getplugin` method](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/e398c93884f228c9808adf9d0be2f876719e703d/src/_pytest/config/__init__.py#L446) of the `PytestPluginManager` to obtain the LoggingPlugin, but I'm afraid I have not found a way of accessing that manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm afraid I have not found a way of accessing that manager.

Use the [`request`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#request) fixture to access the plugin manager in tests:

```
def test_spam(request):
    mgr = request.session.config.pluginmanager
    logging_plugin = mgr.get_plugin("logging-plugin")
```

However, this won't be necessary for changing the live log level (and IIRC changing `LoggingPlugin.log_cli_level` will only have an effect in runtest hooks, not in the test cases or fixtures). The log capturing and live logging share the same log level, so simply use the [`caplog`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#caplog) fixture. Here's a simple example:

```
import logging
import pytest


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def emit_logs():
    logger.info('sample info')
    logger.warning('sample warning')
    logger.error('sample error')
    logger.critical('sample critical')


def test_spam():
    emit_logs()
```

will yield

```
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [    INFO] sample info (test_spam.py:9)
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [ WARNING] sample warning (test_spam.py:10)
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [   ERROR] sample error (test_spam.py:11)
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [CRITICAL] sample critical (test_spam.py:12)
```

Now e.g. raising the level to `CRITICAL`:

```
def test_spam(caplog):
    caplog.set_level(logging.CRITICAL)
    emit_logs()
```

yields only

```
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [CRITICAL] sample critical (test_spam.py:12)
```

Using `caplog` as context manager:

```
def test_spam(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.ERROR):
        emit_logs()
```

will yield

```
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [   ERROR] sample error (test_spam.py:11)
2020-12-11 16:27:41 [CRITICAL] sample critical (test_spam.py:12)
```

Dynamic changing live log level also works,

```
def test_eggs(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.WARNING):
        logger.info("i am not logged")
    logger.info("but i am")
```

as well as moving live log level switch to fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def errors_only(caplog):
    with caplog.at_level(logging.ERROR):
        yield


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("errors_only")
def test_bacon():
    logger.error("i am printed")
    logger.info("but i am not")
```