# Adding system or utility live logs for pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm building a pytest fixture that starts some long process before any tests are executed.

I would like to have utility logs reporting about that process while it's taking place after being initiated by pytest.

The fixture looks something like this:

```py
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@fixture
def some_long_process():

    logger.info("Process started")

    logger.info("Process ongoing..")

    yield

    logger.info("Process ended")
```

The problem is that pytest automatically captures all outputs during test runs and although you can enable live logging I wish I could enable live logging specifically for my logger.

Is there a way to do that? Or alternatively, a way to add system logs to pytest?

Comment: I think this answers the question on how to dynamically set the log level -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65248079/change-pytests-live-log-level-during-runtime

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need to enable [live logs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/logging.html#live-logs).

It can be done directly at the command line by passing the `log_cli_level` .

```sh
pytest --log-cli-level=INFO test_log_feature.py

# ----- live log setup -------------------------------------------
# INFO     test_log_feature:test_log_feature.py:9 Process started
# INFO     test_log_feature:test_log_feature.py:10 Process ongoing..
# PASSED                                                                                                                                                                      [100%]
# ----- live log teardown ----------------------------------------
# INFO     test_log_feature:test_log_feature.py:12 Process ended
```

You can do the same in a `pytest.ini` configuration file.

```
[pytest]
log_cli=true
log_cli_level=INFO
```

### Update

> I want live logging solely for my logger, is that possible?

I think in this case you have to play with loggers and define various loggers according to your needs and enable `log_cli_level` at the lower level you want to see. Here is an example to illustrate this solution.

```py
import logging
import pytest

fixture_logger = logging.getLogger("fixture")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# can also be set by configuration
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

@pytest.fixture()
def some_long_process(caplog):
    fixture_logger.info("Process started")
    fixture_logger.info("Process ongoing..")
    yield
    fixture_logger.info("Process ended")

def test_long_process(some_long_process, caplog, request):
    logger.info("Log I don't want to see")
    pass
```

Gives.

```sh
pytest --log-cli-level=INFO test_log_feature.py
                                                                                                                                                          

# --- live log setup ---
# INFO     fixture:test_log_feature.py:10 Process started
# INFO     fixture:test_log_feature.py:11 Process ongoing..
# PASSED                                                                                                                                                                      [100%]
# ---- live log teardown ---
# INFO     fixture:test_log_feature.py:13 Process ended
```

Comment: This will enable live logging for the whole run. Meaning all logging throughout the run will be printed.
I want live logging solely for my logger, is that possible?

Comment: @Nitzankin I've made an update to propose a solution. Hope it helps.